# How to update a column in MySQL

Tags: python, mysql

I want to update a column in table in MySQL with some information that I retrieved from a website.The name of this column is "names" and the name of the table is "HuntsPointYelp"

I am getting ProgrammingError for my UPDATE query, which I think it is a syntax error.

Thanks!

```
import pymysql

conn = pymysql.connect(host='127.0.0.1', 
unix_socket='/tmp/mysql.sock',user='root', 
passwd='  ', db='mysql', charset='utf8')
cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute('USE HuntsPointsBusinesses')

def storeNames (names):
    cur.execute('UPDATE HuntsPointYelp SET = ("%s")', names)
    cur.connection.commit() 

def getNames (bs):             

#names:
restGrid = bs.find_all ("ul", {"class": "lemon--ul__373c0__1_cxs 
undefined list__373c0__2G8oH"}) 
#namesList = [] 

time.sleep(2)
for i in restGrid: 
    h3 = i.find_all ("h3") 
    for h in h3:          
        target = h.find_all ("a") 
        for t in target: 
            if "name" in t.attrs:              
                if t.attrs is not None: 
                    names = t["name"]

                    storeNames (names)

driver.get ("https://www.yelp.com/search? 
cflt=restaurants&find_loc=Hunts+Point%2C+Bronx%2C+NY+10474")
pageSource = driver.page_source
bs = BeautifulSoup (pageSource, "html.parser")

names = getNames(bs)




ProgrammingError: (1064, 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for 
the right syntax to use near \'= ("\'Roaming Woodfired Pizza\'")\' 
at line 1')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems.

First, you're missing the name of the column to set. Second, you shouldn't put the placeholder in quotes; `cur.execute()` does the necessary quoting for you, so you end up with literal quotes in the value.

```
cur.execute('UPDATE HuntsPointYelp SET names = %s', names)
```